# Migrating SQL dump from Drupal 5 into Drupal 7

Tags: database, migrations

My site went recently down, and all the data were lost (PHP installation of Drupal 5). What I am left is simple SQL dump from PHPMyAdmin.

I would like to "use" this disaster and finally migrate to Drupal 7. Because of this, I do not know how to continue.

Should I install Drupal 5 first, import SQL dump, and then upgrade?

Is there any way how to save stored data from Drupal 5 (SQL dump) to Drupal 7? If the answer is *yes*, can you please point me to correct procedure?

Comment: This question has been answered. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/migration-from-drupal-5-to-7 I'd advocate the approach from http://quicksketch.org/node/5739

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any other way to update to Drupal 7, if not following the steps you listed. I would rather update to Drupal 6, and then to Drupal 7.
Probably, you could avoid installing Drupal 5, if you restore the database tables used from Drupal 5; you could start with updating to Drupal 6, if you have a copy of the setting.php file used from Drupal 5 (or you can *rebuild* it). I have never tried this; it could be working in theory, but have some practical problems I didn't think of.

Updating the data from Drupal 5 to Drupal 7 means to execute the update functions Drupal runs to update itself. There isn't any other method, since Drupal executes the updates in a specific order, and [hook_update_dependencies()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_dependencies/7) implementations change that order.